# PHP and mySQL Data Errors

Tags: php, javascript

I currently have 2 users registered on my website; jason and jason1.

I have a mySQL database that stores the following fields: 
`id message reciever sender`

When a message is sent from jason1 to jason, the data comes up correctly.
However, when a message is sent from jason to jason1 both the `sender` and `reciever` fields come up as having the value of jason1.
Here is some script info:

The way the function is called: http://pastebin.com/BqVQ7vVE
The function itself: http://pastebin.com/1hTEhxAN
`getmessage.php`, called with XHR: http://pastebin.com/u1A4hPG3
And a screenshot of the database: http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/7804/mysqlz.png

I will take any suggestions, this is really frustrating.

Comment: Are you sure cookies are fine?

Comment: where is the message fetching function?  I also notice in your db, you have jason1 as sender in both fields,one he sends for himself, and once to jason.  I would also suggest to sanitize the cookie value in username before putting it in sql directly to avoid sql injections.

Comment: @Dreaded that's the problem, when the user logs in the `username2` cookie is set as their current username, which apparently is jason1 for both users, but that's incorrect.

Comment: I attempted logging in as both `jason` and `jason1`. I had the main page echo out the cookie, and the returned values were correct. I then had the `test.php` page (the one that processes posts on the main page) echo out the cookie and it mysteriously changed to `jason1`.

Comment: I would advise against using cookie to determine current user . instead use session. anyone can manipulate a cookie.

Comment: can you post the function where you set the cookie ?

Comment: @Dreaded I was originally using `$_SESSION`, but they had the tendency to spontaneously unset themselves. The cookie setting function: http://pastebin.com/8fwEPALk

Comment: I created a third user, and the cookie was still set to `jason1`.

Answer (score 0):

to summarize the discussion, the issue is with the cookie,  and according to your set cookie function here: http://pastebin.com/8fwEPALk

```
function validateUser($username){
        session_regenerate_id (); 
        $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: ../new.php");
        setcookie('username2',$_SESSION['username'],time()+60*60*24*365,'/');
    }
```

you made it go header before the setcookie,  you need to place the setcookie before header and also don't forget to add exit after header.  the reason jason1 always in your cookie perhaps from previous working state of your website.

```
function validateUser($username){
        session_regenerate_id (); 
        $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        setcookie('username2',$_SESSION['username'],time()+60*60*24*365,'/');
        header("Location: ../new.php");
            exit;
    }
```

using cookie to validate user login is a security risk , you can debug and find out why session didn't work for you. it could be the session directory is getting wiped out improperly, in that case try to set different folder for the session_path

Comment: Really? I was told that it doesn't matter if the `setcookie()` function was called before or after a header redirect.